# How to open a JPG image and resize it with TensorFlow Serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to publish a model through TensorFlow Serving with Docker via HTTP. I want it to recibe JPG or PNG images (codified in base64) of any size and 1 or 3 channels, but my model can only process opened images of 224x224 with one channel.

I usually open and resize the images with openCV but that is not an option in TF Serving (to my knowledge). How can I open and resize images in TF?

There is a [TF Serving client example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py) which sends an image of any size in JPG or PNG to a ResNet and it works.

Comment: I would suggest an image handling proxy server between you and tensorflow serving (the easy solution)  or to rewrite your model with a node that transform channels and rescales incoming image data. If you choose the later alternative, keep in mind that all functionallity in tensorflow models are not supported when served by tensorflow serving.

Comment: I want to add a node to my model but how can y open the image? Will TF take care of it?

Comment: So it can be quite advanced, if you take a look at this example : https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple
You will need to specify a SignatureDef and decide how you want to represent arbitrary images in that Signature (how you want to convert it). The image needs to have the specified SignatureDef shape. You will then need to send more information about how your image is converted to fill the SignatureDef and then unconvert it before the prediction. I do not have an example code of this. I would recommend reshapeing the images before sending to tensorflow serving.

Comment: @Grebtsew but reshaping large images on the CPU could be not very effective. It would be nice to offload to GPU as much as posible

Comment: @AndrewMatuk then perhaps you should look into using FFMPEG or Gstreamer with gpu support. Just adjust flags to reshape to your wanted size. A project I recommend is the [deepstream](https://medium.com/@fanzongshaoxing/use-nvidia-deepstream-to-accelerate-h-264-video-stream-decoding-8f0fec764778)

Comment: @Grebtsew the goal is to have end-to-end pipeline, not to install several apps and struggle to friend them

Comment: @DavidRubio have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: @DmitriyStartsev No, sorry